# Which NoSQL ... again :), but a different use case

Tags: mongodb, performance, hbase, qlikview, nosql

Suggestions for a NoSQL datastore so that we can push data and generate real time Qlikview reports easily?

Easily means:
1. Qlikview support for reads ([mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) connector available, otherwise maybe can write a JDBC connector, otherwise maybe can write a custom QVX connector to the datastore)

1. Easily adaptable to changes in schema, or schemaless. We change our schema quite frequently ...
2. Java support for writes
3. Super fast reads - real time incremental access, as well as batch access for old data within a time range. I read that Cassandra excels in ranges.
4. Reasonably fast writes
5. Reasonably big data storage - 20 million rows stored per day, about 200 bytes each
6. Would be nice if it can scale for a years worth of data, elasticity not so important.
7. Easy to use, install, and run. Looking at minimal setup and configuration time.
8. Matlabe support for adhoc querying

Initially I don't think we need a distributed system however a cluster is a possibility.

I've looked at Mongodb, Cassandra and Hbase. I don't think going over REST is a good idea due to (theoretically) slower performance.

I'm leaning towards MongoDB at the moment due to its ease of use, matlab support, totally schema less, Qlikview support (beta connector is available). However if anyone can suggest something better that would be great!

Comment: Out of interest, when you mention a beta connector being available, are you referring to the QVSource connector or is there another one?

Comment: Good question. I'm faceing nearly the same setup. Did you find an answer? Do you still use mongoDB?

Comment: I wrote a nodejs based qvx format module that lets me use streams from the mongo driver and create qvx files that I serve to qlikview using http.
https://github.com/kmpm/node-qvx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the server infrastructure you will use, I guess the best choice is amazon's NoSQL service, avalaible in [aws.amazon.com](http://aws.amazon.com).

The fact is any DB will have a poor performance in cloud infrastructure due to the way it stores data, amazon EC2 with EBS for instance is VERY slow for this task, requiring you to connect up to 20 EBS volumes in raid to acquire a decent speed. They solved this issue creating this NoSQL service, which I never used, but seems nice.

Comment: Amazon is just an example, I think some others may have a service just like it. It may seems more expansive, but for such high usage, It will probably be cheaper in long term.